# IF condition with user-defined variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to convert below MS SQL script into equivalent MySQL script(no stored proc or functions).

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE name = 'abc')
BEGIN
    --Call some SP or functions, not just INSERT
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to just do an insert with a where clause:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (...)
SELECT ...
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE name = 'abc');
```

Should the `EXISTS` clause fail, then no records would be inserted.  In order for this to work, you would have to phrase the insert as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.  But, even if you were just planning to insert literal values with a `VALUES` clause, you could still rephrase that into a select.

Comment: what if its not INSERT but say calling some SP or functions

Comment: Well then, it would mean that you've substantially changed your question after others have already taken time to answer the original one.  This could draw downvotes.